# Can`t get the jquery alerts to work on webpages in the web-inf folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, callback

I am trying to implement notifications on my web project its using a mvc design pattern with EJB and JPA. Also the header and footer are in a separate file for each. The problem is that when i try to use the alerts its not working. example code from the fornecedor jsp:

```
 <script src="js2/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <script src="js2/js/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
        <script src="js2/js/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="js2/css/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function gback(){
                document.FM.action = "<c:url value='FModificar'/>";
                document.FM.method = "get";
                document.FM.submit();
              } 
      $(document).ready(function(){ 

              $("#FElim").click(function () {
                jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                    jAlert('success', 'Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
                         if (r) {
                              document.FEliminar.action = "<c:url value='FEL'/>";
                              document.FEliminar.method = "get";
                              document.FEliminar.submit();
                            } else {
                              return false;
                            }
                });
            });

       });

</script>
```

the code of  the script:

```
 <%-- Eliminar Fornecedor is Requested --%> 
                         <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesInF,'FEliminar')}"> 

                              <table id="ProductTable" class="detailsTable">

                                    <tr class="header">
                                        <th colspan="8" >Products</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr class="tableHeading">
                                        <td>ID</td>
                                        <td>Nome</td>
                                        <td>Endereço</td>
                                        <td>Descrição</td>
                                        <td>Nº de Celulare</td>
                                        <td>Nº de Telefone</td>
                                        <td>Email</td>    
                                        <td>Fax</td> 
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <c:forEach var="ELForn" items="${EFornecedorList}" varStatus="iter">

                                        <tr class="${'white'} tableRow">   
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFid()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFNome()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFEndereco()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFDescricao()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFNCel()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFNTel()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFEmail()}</td>
                                            <td>${ELForn.getFFax()}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <form action="<c:url value='FEL'/>" method="post" name="FEliminar">
                                                    <input type="hidden"
                                                           name="MEId"
                                                           value="${ELForn.getFid()}">
                                                    <input id="FElim" type="button"                                                          
                                                           value="Eliminar">                                                       
                                                </form>
                                            </td> 
                                        </tr>

                                    </c:forEach>

                                </table>                                

                        </c:if> 
                        <%-- END Eliminar Fornecedor is Requested --%>
```

here is the header jsp page code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Style.css">        
        <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
        <%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
        <%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %> 
        <script src="/AffableBean/js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <script src="/AffableBean/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/AffableBean/js/jquery.corners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.rounded').corners();

                $('a.categoryButton').hover(
                    function () {$(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#b2d2d2'})},
                    function () {$(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#d3ede8'})}
                );

                $('div.ActionBox').hover(over, out);

                function over() {
                    var span = this.getElementsByTagName('span');
                    $(span[0]).animate({opacity: 0.3});
                    $(span[1]).animate({color: 'white'});

                }

                function out() {
                    var span = this.getElementsByTagName('span');
                    $(span[0]).animate({opacity: 0.7});
                    $(span[1]).animate({color: '#444'});
                }            


            });



        </script>

        <title>Rimpex Stock Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">

            <div id="header">                
                        <a href="<c:url value='Home'/>">
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_R_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo">  
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_I_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo"> 
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_M_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo"> 
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_P_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo"> 
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_E_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo"> 
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_X_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo">
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_L_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo">  
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_T_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo"> 
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/Letter_D_blue_Icon_64.png" id="logo" alt="Rimpex logo">  
                        </a>    


                       <div class="clr"></div>             

                       <div id="Menu">
                           <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesIn,'Home')}">
                                <ul>
                                  <li class="active"><a href="<c:url value='Home'/>"><span class="bigText">Home</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='Utilizador'/>"><span class="bigText">Utilizador</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='LogOff'/>" id="LOf"><span class="bigText">Log Off</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='About'/>"><span class="bigText">About</span></a></li>                                                        
                                </ul>  
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesIn,'Utilizador')}">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='Home'/>"><span class="bigText">Home</span></a></li>
                                  <li class="active"><a href="<c:url value='Utilizador'/>"><span class="bigText">Utilizador</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='LogOff'/>"><span class="bigText">Log Off</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='About'/>"><span class="bigText">About</span></a></li>                                        
                                </ul>  
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesIn,'LogOff')}">

                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesIn,'About')}">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='Home'/>"><span class="bigText">Home</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='Utilizador'/>"><span class="bigText">Utilizador</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='LogOff'/>"><span class="bigText">Log Off</span></a></li>
                                  <li class="active"><a href="<c:url value='About'/>"><span class="bigText">About</span></a></li>                                                       
                                </ul>  
                            </c:if>

                           <c:if test="${fn:contains(PagesIn,'Mar')}">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='Home'/>"><span class="bigText">Home</span></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="<c:url value='About'/>"><span class="bigText">About</span></a></li> 

                                </ul>  
                            </c:if>
                        </div>
                </div>

            <div id="Top1">

                <c:if test="${!empty Cart}">
                    <div id="widgetBar">

                      <%-- checkout widget --%>
                      <div class="headerWidget">
                          <a href="#" class="rounded bubble">Avança a Saida</a>

                      </div>

                    <%-- shopping cart widget --%>
                      <div class="headerWidget" id="viewCart">
                          <a href="#" class="rounded bubble">                  
                          <img src="/StockWebApp/img/cart.gif" alt="shopping cart icon" id="cart">

                          <span class="horizontalMargin">   
                            ${cart.getNumberOfItems()} Itens  
                          </span></a>               
                      </div>                  

                     </div>
                    </c:if>
               </div>               


              <div id="Top"></div>
              <div class="clr"></div>
```

the alerts only work on the index page. So if anyone has any ideas please feel free to share it.

Comment: What have you done to debug it so far? Have you verified that the scripts are even included in the pages when they don't appear to work? Are there errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: I did debug and there are no errors in the JavaScript console only this warning [19:22:01.971] $ is not defined @ http://localhost:8080/StockWebApp/FEliminar:16.The scripts are included in the page but when retrieving the pages i did ind this [19:21:20.699] GET http://localhost:8080/StockWebApp/img/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 9ms]

Comment: Also when retrieving the pages i did ind this [19:21:20.699] GET http://localhost:8080/StockWebApp/js/jquery-1.6.4.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 22ms] and the same for the rest of this files
js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 26ms]

Comment: And js/jquery.corners.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 56ms]
js2/js/jquery.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 42ms]
js2/js/jquery.ui.draggable.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 46ms]
js2/js/jquery.alerts.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 53ms]
js2/css/jquery.alerts.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 58ms]
js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]
js/jquery.corners.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 9ms]

Comment: Well in a page that uses jQuery, the warning, "$ is not defined" will basically mean that absolutely nothing will work. All those 404 errors means that the paths your pages are using to load auxiliary files are wrong. I don't know what they should be because I don't know how your site works.

Comment: but my project works. if you checked my header code there are some functions for creating effects on a square and it works. For the "$ is not defined" warning what do you recommend? And the not found errors should i check the paths of those files?

Comment: Checking the paths would certainly be a good idea. If you fix that, it will probably fix the jQuery problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi changing the path of the JavaScript files fixed  my problem.

```
<script src="/AffableBean/js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/StockWebApp/js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```